# SEGFAULT when passing QString by refernce to library function

Tags: qt, parameters, reference, shared-libraries

I've been fighting with this all day long and I've tried passing a QString, a std::string, and a char* in many many different fashions, but if I pass it so that I can modify the parameter's value inside the library function then it SEGFAULTs. If I copy the library function, line for line, into the main app, I can pass references all day long as params and change their values inside the functions.

Here is the stripped down version of my function inside the library.
I have literally removed all code except for this line.

```
MySQLLib::ExecuteQuery(const QString& query, QString& results)
{
  results = "Changed the value of this parameter.";
}
```

Here is the calling code from the main application.
bmdbTest is an instance of the above MySQLLib class...
All the other code in my library and application works. It just won't let me pass references to ANYTHING to my library.

```
MySQLProj::pbExecuteQuery_Click()
{
  QString x = "Hello.";
  bmdbTest->ExecuteQuery("SELECT ttid from test_table", x);
  ui_MySQLProj1.textEdit->setText(x);
}
```

It SEGFAULTs on the bmdbTest->ExecuteQuery call.
I've even tried a simple int& as a parameter with no success.
I can however pass params as const QString&  without issue. I just can't modify the param's value that way.

EDIT: I just figured it out. Thank you to "paxdiablo" for suggesting I check my variables for null or invalid pointers. I was really tired last night and I can't believe I missed this.

I just found the problem and I feel like a complete idiot. You mentioned about bmdbTest being null or invalid. The value of bmdbTest was fine as all my other functions worked fine, but when I was calling ExecuteQuery() I was passing the query string from the value in a QLineEdit from my GUI window like this.

```
bmdbTest->ExecuteQuery(leQuery->text(), resultString);
```

The leQuery->Text() was actually the problem as I must access leQuery like this.

```
bmdbTest->ExecuteQuery(ui_MySQLProj1.leQuery->text(), resultString);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check the value of `bmdbTest` itself. It may be null or an invalid pointer.

That seems to be indicated by the fact it's faulting on *that* line. If there were something suspect about the parameters, I would expect it to fault *within* the `ExecuteQuery` function.

You should be able to find out *exactly* where the crash is by putting suitable debug statements (with flushing) on either side of the `results = ...` and `bmdbTest->ExecuteQuery(...)` lines (or use a debugger if you have one).